# Probability of being in a group

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I would like to check my reasoning and answer.

> 20 people are selected from a group of 60 candidates. What is the
>   probability of one particular candidate being in the group of 20?

Number of possible groups with the selected candidate and 19 others:

$$\frac{59!}{(59-19)! 19!}$$

Total number of groups of 20:

$$\frac{60!}{(60-20)! 20!}$$

The probability of one particular candidate being in the group of 20:

$$\frac{\binom{59}{19}}{\binom{60}{20}} = \frac{1}{3}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer is spot on! However keep in mind that there is always (ok maybe sometimes) other solutions, like this one:

Imagine distributing $60$ cards, $20$ of which are blue while the rest is red. Those with blue card get selected. Probability of a particular candidate to get any of these $20$ cards is $\frac{20}{60}=\frac{1}{3}$

Answer (score 4):

Yes, your explanation is absolutely correct. However, I would like to present even a simpler explanation for this problem.

Imagine having a dinner table with 60 seats. The table is divided into 2 sections of 20 seats and 40 seats. See the diagram below

[image]

Your problem essentially is to place a particular candidate to 20-seat-section. And you don't care how the rest of other candidates are seated.

Probability of the person getting seated to 20-seat-section is simply $\frac{20}{60}$ = $\frac{1}{3}$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your reasoning and answer are correct.